# Is there any boost-independent version of boost/tr1 shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I'm looking for independent implementation of boost/tr1  `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` and `enable_shared_from_this`.

I need:

- Boost independent very small implementation of these features.
- I need support of only modern compilers like GCC-4.x, MSVC-2008, Intel not things like MSVC6 or gcc-3.3
- I need it to be licensed under non-copyleft LGPL compatible license like Boost/Mit/3-clause BSD.

So I can include it in my library.

Note - it is quite hard to extract shared_ptr from boost, at least BCP gives about 324 files...

Comment: GCC-4.x and MSVC-2008 provide both tr1::shared_ptr. I don't know for intel.

Comment: Why do you need a very SMALL implementation?
Can you include sources with BSL?
Why not to include the whole Boost version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I extracted shared_ptr from Boost to use it separately, and it was definitely fewer than 300 files. That was 3 years ago however so things may have changed (maybe there are more files in the config folder these days?). What I needed for the shared_ptr was:

- assert.hpp
- checked_delete.hpp
- throw_exception.hpp
- config.hpp and config directory
- detail/bad_weak_ptr.hpp
- detail/interlocked.hpp
- detail/shared_count.hpp
- detail/sp_counted_base.hpp
- detail/sp_counted_base_w32.hpp
- detail/sp_counted_impl.hpp
- detail/workaround.hpp
- and finally, shared_ptr.hpp itself.

I don't think weak_ptr and enable_shared_from_this will add a lot of files to that.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of GCC include an implementation of TR1.

```
#include <tr1/memory>
```

This gives you all three things you mention, in the `std::tr1` namespace.

Comment: -1 The OP want a portable version working on GCC-4.x, MSVC-2008, Intel 
As some version of these compiler don't provide this file he needed boost/tr1.

Comment: @Vicente where is that -1 you said you casted?

Comment: I meant that the answer doesn't respond to the question.

Answer (score 1):

BCP work at the component level, so any dependency between components result in an explosion of the number of files.

I would try to include the files that I need an those that the compiler tell me that are not found, one by one. When your product is build you should have the needed files.

This should reduce a lot the number of files, at the expenses of some of your time.

It would be clearly a must if BCP was able to do this for you: worked at the file level and not at the component level, and was able to take care of conditional compilation.